# Can't bind click with function in durandal

Tags: durandal

Can't bind click with function in durandal

ViewModel:

```
define(function (require) {
    var system = require('durandal/system');
    var app = require('durandal/app');
    var router = require('durandal/plugins/router');
return {

        activate: function () {

        },
 addIdea: function () {
        debugger;
    }
};

});
```

Button on view:

```
<input type="button" data-bind='click:addIdea' value="Add" />
```

Will appreciate any suggestion!

Comment: Is that all the code of the view? Can you provide the full code?

Comment: the rest of view is inputs and labels, is it realy important?

Comment: Wouldn't it be great if questions asked in two places at the same time could be answered in ONE place? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/durandaljs/lNj07cTrIYY
Unfortunately we're not there yet.

Comment: Dear @RainerAtSpirit, I didn't get any response here so I tried at google groups.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. It's really a complaint about synchronizing two incompatible systems... but wouldn't it be great IF :). For the time being I think you got an answer in 

google, so test it and if it works provide the answer here.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand you. I will do it asap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me:

```
 define(['repositories/vmRepository', 'durandal/app', 'durandal/plugins/router'], function (vmRepository, app, router) {

  idea:ko.validatedObservable({
          ...
        }),
 activate: function () {
        },

   addIdea: function () {
        }
    }
return vm;
```

View:

```
<div data-bind="with: idea">
...
  <input type="button" data-bind='click: $parent.addIdea' value="Add" />
</div>
```